# Read several tables to the same data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I read several tables to the same data frame

```
i = 0
while (condition): 
        dfMoreData = sqlContext.read.parquet("data" + i + ".parquet")
        # process dfMoreData
        i = i + 1
```

I encounter exceptions regarding out of memory 
Should and how  I clear dfMoreData after each iteration?

Comment: Excuse me but that approach is incorrect since the start. Because `dfMoreData` exists only in that `while` scope.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the code that's not assigning the immutable values to any collection, one way is to use regex or path filter

```
sqlContext.read.parquet("data*.parquet");
```

reduce your dataframes using unionAll

```
val df = (1 to 10) // assuming filenames are 1 to 10
  .map("data" + _ + ".parquet")
  .map(sqlContext.read.parquet(_))
  .reduce(_ unionAll _)
```

For out of memory error, I believe the cluster needs to have enough memory to load the data. After that you can try to persist with MEMORY_AND_DISK option and do the rest.

Comment: @Yakov  if this answers your question, can you accept it?